# Primefaces orderlist submitting wrong string representation of list

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I have a Primefaces orderlist with a custom converter.  Basically it is to convert a Document object to/from a Json representation. I am confident that conversion from object to Json is correct.  Chrome browser "element inspection" shows a correct Json in the data-item-value attribute:

```
<li class="ui-orderlist-item ui-corner-all ui-sortable-handle" 
data-item-value="{ "order" : 0, "label" : "label", "values" : ["Hey0", "0"] }"><table><tbody><tr><td>[Hey0, 0]</td></tr></tbody></table></li> ...
```

But on an ajax post back, the value submitted becomes:

main-form:rows_values: [object Object]

where I would expect "object" would be the json in the data-item-value attribute.  So there is no way conversion to object succeeds.  It is therefore most likely due to wrong usage in the facelets page:

```
<p:orderList id="rows" value="#{bean.rows}" converter="datarow" itemValue="#{row}" var="row">
            <p:column>
                #{row.values}
            </p:column>
</p:orderList>
```

But this usage is copied from Primefaces showcase.  So what's wrong?

I am using Mojarra 2.2.12, Primefaces 6.1.

Comment: [mcve] please... You seem to be (ab)using things since the PF showcase works and it works for me with a converter as well (no conversion to json but to an 'id'). Might very well be that the comma in your json has a meaning in PrimeFaces in the submission of multiple fields to the server

Comment: An example is in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394128/primefaces-orderlist-custom-converter-submitting-wrong-string-representation-on

Comment: Why did you create a new question? Then remove this one.