# Primefaces orderlist custom converter submitting wrong string representation on ajax post back

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I need to reshuffle the order of some data models in a list, so I use Primefaces orderlist.  The facelet is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="main-form">
        <p:panelGrid id="grid" columns="3">
            <p:outputLabel value="Name" for="label"/> 
            <p:inputText id="label" value="#{sampleBean.obj.name}" />
            <p:message for="label"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
        <br/><p:commandButton value="Add" action="#{sampleBean.addToList()}" update="@form" />
        <br/>
        <p:orderList id="rows" value="#{sampleBean.list}" converter="sample2" 
                     itemValue="#{row}" var="row">
            <p:column>
                #{row.name}
            </p:column>
        </p:orderList>
        <br/><p:commandButton value="Export" action="#{sampleBean.export()}" update="@form" />
    </h:form>
    <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The backing bean is:

```
@javax.inject.Named
@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
public class SampleBean implements java.io.Serializable {
private List<SampleModel> list;
private SampleModel obj;

public SampleBean() {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    obj = new SampleModel();
    obj.setName("");
}

public void addToList() {
    list.add(obj);
    obj = new SampleModel();
    obj.setName("");
}

public void export() {
    StringBuilder buf= new StringBuilder();
    for (SampleModel m: list) {
        buf.append(m.getName()).append(',');
    }
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(buf.toString());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public List<SampleModel> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<SampleModel> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public SampleModel getObj() {
    return obj;
}

public void setObj(SampleModel obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
}
}
```

The sample model is:

```
public class SampleModel {

private String name;
private String uname;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.uname = name.toUpperCase();
}

public String getUname() {
    return uname;
}

public void setUname(String uname) {
    this.uname = uname;
}
}
```

Using a simple converter is OK.  But since my real usage has a flexible structure, so the object will gonna be org.bson.Document. The following converter using a JSON representation does not work:

```
@FacesConverter("sample2")
public class Sample2Converter  implements Converter {

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    SampleModel model = new SampleModel();
    try {
        Document d = Document.parse(value);
        model.setName(d.getString("name"));
    }
    catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        model.setName("exception");
        Logger.getLogger("Sample2Converter").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return model;
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value instanceof SampleModel) {
        SampleModel model = (SampleModel)value;
        return new Document().append("name", model.getName()).append("uname", model.getUname()).toJson();
    }
    else
        return "invalid";
}

}
```

From Chrome browser debug, upon ajax post back, the list is submitting 
main-form:rows_values: [object Object]
instead of 
main-form:rows_values: {"name":"apple"}

I am using Mojarra 2.2.12, Primefaces 6.1.

Comment: Like stated in the other question, a comma might mean something in this component. I don't see any reason you should return a json string as the 'toString' for the converter. Try using just a single non-json field. Does it work then.

Comment: A non-json toString method works fine.  I think the problem is that the json string fools the Primefaces script.  If characters like comma or brace cause problem, Primefaces should escape it transparently, or at least state this in the documentation.

Comment: Nobody is perfect. Check the source to see if that really is the case. The source IS open. And if it is indeed the reason, file an issue in the issue list and if you think it should be escaped instead of just documented you can even create a patch and  file a pullrequest

Comment: A comma alone is not a problem, I verified that. But a well-formed JSON string is.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to json fools the Primefaces script.  As a work around, I use base64 encode/decode in the custom converter and solved the problem.

Comment: creative! compliments

Comment: you did not check which character fools the component?

Comment: It seems that whenever the string is a VALID JSON, it breaks.  For example {"abc":"def"} breaks it, ["abc","def"] also breaks it.  But {}",abc does not break it.

Comment: So maybe it is the " that actually breaks it?

Comment: No a"b"c does not break it.